# Function to write cells in excel

Tags: c#, excel, nullreferenceexception

I get a bit of code from here: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/71788-reading-excel-files-in-c/ which works fine and is easy to understand for me. It can only read excel cells tho, and I want to write some too. 
So I want to do this in my main: excel_setValue("C10", "520");

This is what I tried as function:

```
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel;
    private static Workbook newWorkbook = null;
    private static _Worksheet objsheet = null;


static string excel_setValue(string cellname, string value)  
        {
            if (objsheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString() == string.Empty) // Here is error
            {
                Console.WriteLine("watch out u trying to overwrite files");
            }
            else
            {
                objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(value);
            }         
        }
```

It tells me: NullReferenceExpection was unhandled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Another error I got when I only put this:

```
static void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value)
        {
            //if (objsheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString() == string.Empty)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("kijk uit je probeerd cellen te overschrijven");
            //}
            //else
            //{
                objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(value);
            //}         
        }
```

Error: COMException was unhandled: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

How I call my excel_setValue:

```
excel_init("C:\\");
excel_setValue("B10","520");
```

excel_init:

```
static void excel_init(String path)
        {
            appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                // then go and load this into excel
                newWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
                objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to open file!");
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                appExcel = null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: If get_Range returns null, you will get that error for get_Value(). Please show how you're calling the excel_setValue method.

Comment: Within this method (this scope), `objsheet` does not exist. Or is it defined within the encapsulating class?

Comment: Edited those 2 question in my main question

Comment: ok, looks like you're not setting objsheet as Melvin pointed out. `private static _Worksheet objsheet = null;` It's null here, and never set before calling `get_Range`

Comment: I added my init to the question, it is happening in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the code you linked in the method `excel_init`, you need to initialize `objsheet`. It is done on this line in the link:

```
objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
```

For this edit in your question:

```
How I call my excel_setValue:

excel_setValue("B10","520");
excel_init("C:\\");
```

Is that the order of execution you're using? You have to call `excel_init` first and initialize objsheet before using it in `excel_setValue`.

You may be using [get_Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx) incorrectly, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363163/fastest-way-to-get-an-excel-range-of-rows) for further examples.

You are also using [Range.set_Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.set_value.aspx) incorrectly, try using `objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault,value);`

Comment: I added the init method in my code to the questoin, it is in this part of the code

Comment: No this is not the order I execute, it was a speed error.

Comment: I'm seeing [get_Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx) as taking two parameters...

Comment: objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Type.Missing, value); this fixed the error, but it doenst print the data in the excel table ??? sorry im new in this

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted when you can. Also as a side note, interop is notorious for memory leaks if not used correctly, not to mention it requires Excel to be installed. I'd check out [closed xml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) if you continue doing excel creation/manipulation.