# How can I get a range object from the row and column index using Excel Interop?

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I'm learning VB.Net and trying to transition from VBA.  How can I retrieve a range typed object using the row and column index?

In VBA I would use `Worksheet.Cells([Row,Column])` and that would return an object of type `Range`.
However using the Excel Interop the return is typed as `Object`.
*Example:*

```
Dim MyExcel as new Application
Dim MyBook as new Workbook=MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("SomePath\SomeFile.xlsx")
Dim MySheet as new Worksheet=MyBook.Sheets("SomeSheet")
MessageBox.Show(CStr(Sheet2015.Cells(1, 1).Value))
```

Now, [the MSDN for Worksheet.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.cells.aspx) says:

> Because the ***Item*** property is the default property for the **Range**
>   object, you can specify the row and column index immediately after the
>   Cells keyword. For more information, see the Item property.

But the link to the Item property from that page takes you to [Worksheet.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.item.aspx), NOT Range.Item - so maybe it should say

> "The ***Item*** property is the default property for the **Worksheet**
>   object..."

The return of the Worksheet.Item property is an object of type `Object`, which explains why I don't get intellisense :(

So is there another method I can use that returns a ***Range*** object from a worksheet by providing the index (Row,Column) of the cell, instead of the address?

I know I can use `Worksheet.Range` and provide the A1 referenced address, but this to me is far more convoluted than just using the row and column index.

I also know I can cast the `Worksheet.Cells[R,C]` as type `Range`, but I'd prefer to find a way to return a range.  (See [my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147057/when-to-turn-off-option-strict-or-how-to-deal-with-inheritance-of-com-using-opt) about working with COM objects as base type `Object`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to get a Range directly- I just cast the output of Worksheet.Cells(r,c).  Feels dirty, but all COM interop feels dirty to me.

If you're interested in more typeful Excel interop you might want to check out http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439 .

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I will have to check that library out.  Very cool.  I agree with COM seeming dirty.  Dirtier than I like at least.  Seems like you really need to turn Option Strict off to work with COM objects, or else you end up typecasting everywhere - which I really don't like because you end up hardcoding type in multiple locations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to get an Excel Range of Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363163/fastest-way-to-get-an-excel-range-of-rows)

Comment: @T.S. - The link provided shows a solution of how to select an entire row by specifying `row:row` however as far as I know there is no way using `.Range` to specify `Row,Column` as numbers.  AFAIK the `Range` member wants to see row specified as an integer (1, 2, 3, etc.) and column as a string (A, B, C, YYY, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the range as follows:

```
sheetName.Range(sheetName.Cells(row1, col1), sheetName.Cells(row2, col2))
```

Then you can use this range for whatever you want.

Yes, I realise this answer is very late, but I just ran into the same problem...

Comment: Thanks DrDonut I know your solution is late, and my comment is late, but after looking for a few hours this was the answer that doesn't throw COM (or other) errors in my Excel addin project.