# How to iterate on Excel.Range with an index in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm writing a c# Add in for excel that takes values from a column of an excel sheet and does some operations. This is a part of the code that I wrote:

```
        Excel.Range aqRange = currentSheet.Range["C3:C" + cRowCount];
        Excel.Range vcRange = currentSheet.Range["D3:D" + cRowCount];
        Excel.Range k0R = currentSheet.Range["F2"];
        double[] sgVett = new double[cRowCount];

        foreach (Range aq in aqRange)
        {
            if (i == 0) sgVett[i] = k0R.Value + aq.Value;
            else sgVett[i] = sgVett[i - 1] + aq.Value;
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;

        foreach (Range vc in vcRange)
        {
            if (i == 0) sgVett[i] -= vc.Value;
            else sgVett[i] -= vc.Value;
            i++;
        }
```

I want to know if is there some way to do something like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j<cRowCount; j++) {
    if (i == 0) sgVett[i] = k0R.Value + aqRange[i].Value;
    else sgVett[i] = sgVett[i - 1] + aqRange[i].Value;
}
```

I know that I can't use a `Excel.Range` as a vector, but is there some way to use an index to scroll `aqRange` and `vcRange` or, at least, if it's possible to use just one `for` or one `foreach` instead of two (as I done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Range's [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.cells?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Cells) property a bit like a 2 dimensional array.

It is important to note that although the syntax used is similar to a C# 2D array (Cells[RowIndex, ColIndex]), the  Cells property accesses a COM object that uses 1 as it's start offset, rather than 0.

So you should be able to write something like :

```
for(int j = 1; j<=cRowCount; j++)
{
    if (i == 0) sgVett[i] = k0R.Value + aqRange.Cells[j,1].Value;
}
```

Also see here : [Fastest way to get an Excel Range of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363163/fastest-way-to-get-an-excel-range-of-rows/12367179) & [How do I get an Excel range using row and column numbers in VSTO / C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333202/how-do-i-get-an-excel-range-using-row-and-column-numbers-in-vsto-c/25128437)